# How do I get the current VSCode profile name, from a custom extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a custom vscode extension for private use within the office, just to help us do a load of stuff quicker internally.

It interacts with vscode via cli sometimes, just for a couple of really specific use cases. The recent profiles change means that this only works for the default profile now, not custom ones.
I need to get the profile name to pass in the CLI, as shown here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_command-line

How can I get the profile name of the current window / workspace, with a custom extension, to pass to cli?

I've tried searching on the docs and in the exposed types during development, I can't find anything.

The only thing I have been able to find which might work is that the `window.title` setting has been updated to include `${profileName}`, however, I cannot find how I would resolve this to a value.

Edit:
I've created an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177463
and it's been added to backlog, so it looks like the capability doesn't yet exist.

Comment: I can't find a command that would return the current profile name, you can submit a feature request at the VSC repo, I found a strange named command `workbench.profiles.actions.profileEntry.5fa83d55` (Insiders 1.75) I wonder what that would do

Comment: @rioV8 That is one of your custom profiles that you created.  Setting a keybinding to it switches to that profile.  Note there is also this: `workbench.profiles.actions.profileEntry.__default__profile__`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mark I have never done anything with profiles, I just looked in keybindings for `profile` commands. No `...profileEntry.__default__profile__` in my v1.75 insiders)